# How to package for Phonegap Build - after update files are no longer copied to Bld folder

Tags: visual-studio-2015, phonegap-build, visual-studio-cordova

I've been using the Apache Tools for Cordova since CTP 3 together with Phonegap Build (PGB) to build into APK and IPA files.

I used to do this by zipping the folder that was copied to the Bld folder when I used the "Deploy" function in VS and then adding in a different config.xml that works with PGB.

Since I updated to the latest version of the Apache tools for Visual Studio, only a "changeList.json" is written to the Bld folder.

My question is how can I quickly and easily package the solution so that I can compress and upload to PGB?

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio 2015, the root of the project is now a standard Cordova project so there is no need to use the contents of the bld folder.

See http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/convert_cordova_phonegap/

Comment: Thanks. Compressing just the www folder did the job